# (C DSA) Why are char positions written using fputc() are off by one when read by fgetc() and searched?

Tags: c, file, search

Both write() and search() use the same O(n) for loop but the search reports match position values one less than the write() reports writing them. Is there something that changes when a byte is written or is there something wrong with the read / search logic concerning the file start? The few related questions I found had to do with copying arrays and messing up indices, here it's a 1:1 basic for loop reporting different results as far as I understand for search and write cases.

```
void write() {
    char ch_a = 'A', ch_b = 'B', ch_null = '\0';
    FILE *p_file = fopen(pch_fname, "w");
    if (p_file != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_out_len_bytes; i++) {
            if (i % (999 * 777) == 0) {
                printf("%d\n", i); //informs B's position
                fputc(ch_b, p_file); //writes B instead of A
            }else{
                fputc(ch_a, p_file); //writes A
            }
        }
        fputc(ch_null, p_file);
    }
    fclose(p_file);
}

void read() {
    FILE *p_file = fopen(pch_input_fname, "r");
    int n_size = -1;
    int n_malloc = 30 * 1024 * 1024;
    int n_char;
    pch_input = (char *) malloc((ssize_t) n_malloc);
    if (p_file != NULL) {
        while (n_char = fgetc(p_file)) {
            n_size++;
            pch_input[n_size - 1] = n_char;
        }
        pch_input[n_size] = '\0';
    }
    fclose(p_file);
    n_input_len = n_size;
}

void search() {
    char *pch_pattern = "B";
    int n_end_i = n_input_len - n_pattern_len;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_end_i; i++)
        if (pch_input[i] == pch_pattern[0])
            printf("%c == %c at i:%d\n", pch_input[i], pch_pattern[0], i); // outputs B
            //^^ expected to output same position as write() but outputs 'write().i-1'
        if (i % (999 * 777) == 0)
            printf("%c == %c at i:%d\n", pch_input[i], pch_pattern[0], i); // outputs A
}
```

Comment: Newlines in windows maybe?

Answer (score 1):

n_size in read() initialized to -1 and n_size - 1 is used to store the read output to string which does not fail in this case:

> read starts out with int n_size = -1;. The while uses n_size++; and then stores in pch_input[n_size - 1]. The first character is stored in index [-1]. That should cause problems, but the characters are all off by one. – user3121023 2

Thank you so much, cannot believe I missed it!

Either initializing n_size = 0 or storing at n_size (vs n_size -1) fixes it. Search and write are both fine.